# Narrowing Conversion meaning in cpp

Tags: c++

I have this C++ code

```
int a=3;
float r{a};
float b=4.0f;
int p{b};
```

and it throws this warning in compiler

```
warning: narrowing conversion of 'a' from 'int' to 'float' [-Wnarrowing]
     float r{a};
             ^ 
warning: narrowing conversion of 'b' from 'float' to 'int' [-Wnarrowing]
         int p{b};
```

I am not able to understand why is converting from int to float is a narrowing conversion ? It should be widening conversion right ?

Comment: Assuming 4 byte int and 4 byte float, then some integer values cannot be represented as floats and obviously some floats cannot be represented as integers, so both are narrowing conversions

Comment: Assuming 4 byte int and 8 byte double, then int to double is a widening conversion since an 8 byte double would (typically) have a 53 bit mantissa, so all integers can be represented as doubles.

Comment: It is not about the approximate value, but about the exact value, which possibly cannot be represented. `float` uses bits for the exponent, so less bits are left for the actual number (mantissa + implicit 1 + sign bit), if the `int` does not just end in a lot of zeroes as the least significant bits, which can be represented by the exponent of the `float`. The current compilers expect you to write an explicit cast in those cases to show that you intended and accepted this behavior.

Comment: As soon as the Contracts feature is standardized, often the range of the used `int` variables will be limited by pre- and post-conditions, preventing this effect in the first place. In those cases, an explicit cast probably won't be necessary any more.

Comment: A narrowing conversion changes a value to a data type that might not be able to hold some of the possible values. Hence it is possible that conversion between two types would be narrowing in either way.

Answer (score 6):

> why is converting from int to float is a narrowing conversion ?

```
int i = 2147483647;
float f = i;
std::cout << i <<< ' ' << f << '\n';
# 2147483647 2147483648.000000
```

`float` is not able to represent all values that `int` can represent *. It is a narrowing conversion.

And vice versa, `int` is not able to represent all values that a `float` can - a fraction.

> It should be widening conversion right ?

Float is able to represent a greater range of values, but it is not able to accurately represent all values in `int` range.

---

* - note: `int` has *at least* 16 bits and `float` is something platform dependent. On a platform where `int` *is* 16 bits and `float` is half IEEE745, then `int` -> `float` would *not* be a narrowing conversion. Most commonly nowadays, `int` has 32 bits, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models .

---

> Ok thanks. But for "int a2=5; long double d{a2};" I get a compiler warning "warning: narrowing conversion of 'a2' from 'int' to 'long double' [-Wnarrowing]".

This was a "human" answer, but if you are interested in "language lawyer" answer, a "narrowing conversion" is a defined term https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#def:conversion,narrowing :

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> - from a floating-point type to an integer type
> - [...]
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type, or
> - [...]

Although `long double` is able to represent all values of `int`, the `long double d{a2};` is not a constant expression, so the point does not apply here, and the conversion is still narrowing.

Comment: Ok thanks. But for "int a2=5; long double d{a2};" I get a compiler warning "warning: narrowing conversion of 'a2' from 'int' to 'long double' [-Wnarrowing]". 
Size of long double is 16bytes and size of int is 4bytes.

Comment: I updated my answer. You are right - this answer was lacking.

Answer (score 2):

List-initialization (meaning initialization with braces) has a rule since C++11 that it may not perform *narrowing conversions*. If it does, the program is ill-formed. GCC is being nice by still compiling it and only warning instead of stopping compilation with an error.

In the sense of this rule *any* conversion from an integer to a floating-point type or the other way around is considered a *narrowing conversion*, except when the argument is a constant expression in the former case and the value can be represented in the target type exactly.

Narrowing conversions are potentially lossy, i.e. the round-trip conversion typically is not guaranteed to reproduce the original value. For example a `float` can typically not represent all integer values of a `int` *exactly* and conversion back to `int` from the `float` may produce a different value than the original one.

The rule doesn't differentiate for situations where the floating point type happens to be able to represent all values of the integer type exactly.

The rule is supposed to protect from mistakes caused by information loss in the conversion. If you decide that you still want the conversion, you can apply it explicitly with `static_cast` to the argument (or use any other initialization form besides those with braces).

See also [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions) for details.