# understanding the difference between Wnarrowing and Wconversion

Tags: c++, types, casting, g++, warnings

The following code in my opinion is a narrowing conversion:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

void f1(int32_t i) {
  std::cout << i << "\n";
}

int64_t f2() {
  return -1;
}

int main([[maybe_unused]] int a1, [[maybe_unused]] char ** a2) {
   int i;
   uint64_t ll = pow(2, 49);
   i = ll;
   std::cout << ll << "\n";
   std::cout << i << "\n";

   f1(ll);
   i = f2();
}
```

However, when i compile it with  `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wnarrowing narrowing.cc` I get no warnings; when I throw in `-Wconversion` it finally freaks out with:

```
narrowing.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
narrowing.cc:16:8: warning: conversion from 'uint64_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} to 'int' may change value [-Wconversion]
   16 |    i = ll;
      |        ^~
narrowing.cc:20:7: warning: conversion from 'uint64_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} to 'int32_t' {aka 'int'} may change value [-Wconversion]
   20 |    f1(ll);
      |       ^~
narrowing.cc:21:10: warning: conversion from 'int64_t' {aka 'long int'} to 'int' may change value [-Wconversion]
   21 |    i = f2();
      |        ~~^~
```

But Wconversions is too melodramatic for my taste.  I only want to see actual irreversible narrowing loss of data.

Comment: The narrowing conversation is defined in the C++ standard as a C++ diagnostics since C++11 that happens while implicit conversion from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type. See the standard. Your example is not an implicit conversion. Try pass a uint64_t variable to an int function parameter.

Comment: @273K see update.  None of this appears to be narrowing to g++ (also tested in Clang and it offers something called -Wshorten-64-to-32 but -Wnarrowing also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [Narrowing Conversion meaning in cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75780796/narrowing-conversion-meaning-in-cpp)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67787920/narrowing-conversion-error-using-newer-compiler - an example of a narrowing conversion raised w/ `-Wall`.

Comment: [A narrowing conversion is also an implicit conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780832/12002570)